# look and feel seaglass look and feel exception

Tags: java, swing

I have created an gui and i used the seaglasslookandfeel and i have the jar file in my buildpath and i get an exception

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class Main {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
                    Main window = new Main();
                      window.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                       window.frame.pack();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Panel p=new Panel();
        frame.add(p);

    }

}
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassContext.getContext(SeaGlassContext.java:145)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.getContext(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:154)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:128)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:123)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:113)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SeaGlassLookAndFeel.java:2286)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:130)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:123)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:113)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SeaGlassLookAndFeel.java:2286)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:130)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:123)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:113)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SeaGlassLookAndFeel.java:2286)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:130)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:123)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:113)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SeaGlassLookAndFeel.java:2286)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:130)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:123)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:113)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SeaGlassLookAndFeel.java:2286)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:130)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:123)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:113)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SeaGlassLookAndFeel.java:2286)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:130)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:123)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyleWrapper.installDefaults(SeaGlassStyleWrapper.java:113)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SeaGlassLookAndFeel.java:2286)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.updateStyle(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:130)
    at com.seaglasslookandfeel.ui.SeaGlassPanelUI.propertyChange(SeaGlassPanelUI.java:217)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Don't mix heavy and light components, like adding a `Panel` on a `JFrame`. This [article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) will provide more information.

Comment: also it is nice to actually ask some question. Buy I guess in your case it is why am I getting this exception, right? @Alpine (+1) very well spot, and I love the article I always recommend the same one in such cases :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is working on my computer.

I used `seaglasslookandfeel-0.1.7.3.jar` library from the [Sea Glass Look and Feel for Swing website](http://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/downloads.html)

I get the following output

[image: output screenshot]

Here is the code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class SeaGlassLNFTest {

        private JFrame frame;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
                        SeaGlassLNFTest window = new SeaGlassLNFTest();
                        window.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        //window.frame.pack();
                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public SeaGlassLNFTest(){
            initialize();
        }

        private void initialize() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Panel p = new Panel();
            frame.add(p);
        }
}
```

---

Although I have added `java.awt.Panel` to a `javax.swing.JFrame`, it should be avoided. Here is an [article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) mentioning the reasons of what to expect when mixing heavyweight and lightweight components.

Swing Look and Feel is for Swing(lightweight) components and not applicable to heavyweight components.

---